# What is compose equivalent of OvershootInterpolator?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

On Android views, we had an animation using an `OvershootInterpolator`

We want to replicate the same animation in Jetpack Compose.
I see that there are several AnimationSpec described in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation but I don't see which one might replicate the `OvershootInterpolator`

- `tween` spec doesn't seem to do any overshoot, just animating between start and end value without overshooting
- `spring` spec does overshooting, however it doesn't have a `durationMillis` parameter as tween, so we can't control how fast it plays
- `keyFrames` spec seems a possible solution by doing something like this:

  ```
            animationSpec = keyframes {
                durationMillis = 500
                0f at 100 with FastOutSlowInEasing
                // Overshoot value to 50f
                50f * 2 at 300 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
                // Actual final value after overshoot animation
                25f at 500
            }
  ```

Is there a better / simpler way than using `keyFrames` to replicate `OvershootInterpolator`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use any `Interpolator` from `Animator` world via a custom `Easing`:

```
animationSpec = tween(easing = Easing {
    OvershootInterpolator().getInterpolation(it) 
})
```

See `Easing` interface: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/core/Easing

Though I would recommend using springs over interpolators, especially ones that mimic springs. Springs would give a much more natural look. :)

Comment: This is not even close what Overshoot does in Android views and why you think **"Springs would give a much more natural look"**? Observation or you just coined this line just for the sake of it?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spring animation` of compose to achieve `OvershootInterpolator`. Even though we cannot provide any custom duration for the animation, we can control the speed of the animation using the `stiffness` attribute.

We can put any custom `float values` to the `stiffness` attribute.
`androidx.compose.animation.core` currently provides `4 stiffness` constant values by default i.e,

```
object Spring {
    /**
     * Stiffness constant for extremely stiff spring
     */
    const val StiffnessHigh = 10_000f

    /**
     * Stiffness constant for medium stiff spring. This is the default stiffness for spring
     * force.
     */
    const val StiffnessMedium = 1500f

    /**
     * Stiffness constant for a spring with low stiffness.
     */
    const val StiffnessLow = 200f

    /**
     * Stiffness constant for a spring with very low stiffness.
     */
    const val StiffnessVeryLow = 50f
    .....
}
```

We can check which `stiffness` suits our case.

For eg:- (medium speed)

```
animationSpec = spring(
    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy,
    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium // with medium speed
)
```

We can also put a custom value to the `stiffness` for eg:-

```
 animationSpec = spring(
    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy, // this would define how far the overshoot would happen.
    stiffness = 1000f // with custom speed less than medium speed.
)
```

You can play around with `custom float values` for stiffness to achieve your ideal duration for the animation.